# Исчезает ползунок при прокрутке слайдера.

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, joomla

Есть joomla 1.6 и нужно встроить туда скроллер для просмотра картинок. Использовал два плагина к jQuery 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/multimedia_portfolio
и
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/making-a-content-slider-with-jquery-ui/

Но для каждого из этих плагинов при прокрутке исчезает (fadeout) ползунок. Проверял на Chrome и Firefox. Результат один и тот же.

Comment: По второй ссылке в демо ничего не исчезает, приведите пожалуйста свой код и параметры, которые вы передаете плагину.

Comment: По первой тоже не исчезает.

Answer (score 1):

Нашла такое решение: "Открываем файл плагина "jquery.ui-slider.js" и заменяем в нем "slide" на "superslide" (ищите полное соответствие, к примеру заменять "slider" уже нельзя). Должно быть 2 соответствия." Мне помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Решил поднять старую тему, потому что сам не давно мучался с решением данной проблемы... Jpuery ui не дружит с новыми версиями mootools изза этого происходит исчезновение слайдера! Решил для себя так: в шаблоне поставил проверку на свой компонент и отключил вывод mootools для него. Мне помогло! Если у кого то есть более изящное решение приглашаю к обсуждению!:) может и у себя переделаю...

Comment: а noConflict пробовали

Comment: да конечно! без noConflict вообще не совместим jquery с mootools